# Can't force arm mode in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, arm

I use Android Studio 2.3.3 and CMake 3.6 (latest in Android SDK).
How can I force arm mode?
Tried 
set(ANDROID_ARM_MODE arm) and 
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE arm)
in CMakeLists.txt, not succeded.
And I found CMAKE_ANDROID_ARM_MODE variable in docs only for cmake > 3.6.
Does it mean, that I can't do this on CMake 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In module's build.gradle, try

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm'
        }
    }
}
```

might check for .externalNativeBuild/.../android_gradle_build.json to see it is set to -marm in compile flags